# ID do componente não aparece na MainActivity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-activity, id

O problema é o seguinte, eu adiciono um componente na minha ActivityMain, um botão por exemplo, mas quando vou fazer o findviewById(ID) do componente, não aparece o ID dele na MainActivity, estava funcionando normal antes, mas agora fui add um novo botão e não aparece mais o ID dele, ele aparece na ActivityMain, coloco um ID nele normal, mas na hora de fazer o findviewById, o ID não aparece. Estou tendo esse problema pela segunda, da primeira vez eu resolvi, mas tive que criar outro projeto, copiar todos os código pro outro projeto e aí voltou ao normal e consegui add o componente, mas não queria ter que fazer isso pela segunda vez, gostaria de entender o pq disso estar acontecendo.

Answer (score 0):

O problema mais provável é que você não está definido o atributo de ID da forma correta ou ele não está no arquivo R.

 
Primeiro verifique se você está definindo o atributo id do componente:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button" />
```

Se sim faça o build do projeto para que as referências sejam adicionadas no arquivo R

Answer (score 0):

O problema era que o Android Studio não tava meio que atualizando os componentes que eu colocava, eu continuei os trabalhos no código até que uma hora o android studio deu uma pequena taravada, aí resolvi procurar pelo ID do componente e ele tava lá, na verdade, o problema não deve ter sido nem do Android Studio em si, mas sim com meu notebook que tava sobrecarregado com várias abas no chrome abertas também.